# MySQL: what does @@ mean?

Tags: mysql

I am reading the MySQL documentation on this page: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/set-statement.html

It often uses "@@", but does not define what "@@" means.

Another example is in variable names:

```
mysql> select @@hostname;
+------------+
| @@hostname |
+------------+
| server1    |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select @hostname;
+-----------+
| @hostname |
+-----------+
| NULL      |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

What is @ vs @@?

Answer (score 20):

### `@@` - System Variable

`@@` is used for [*system variables*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html). Using different suffix with `@@`, you can get either *session* or *global* value of the system variable.

When you refer to a system variable in an expression as `@@var_name` (that is, when you do not specify `@@global.` or `@@session.`), MySQL returns the session value if it exists and the global value otherwise. (This differs from `SET @@var_name = value`, which always refers to the session value.)

---

### `@` - User-Defined Variable

While `@` is used for [*user-defined variables*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html).

---

#### More Details

For more detailes read the following section from the official MySQL Reference Manual:

- [SET Statements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/set-statement.html)

Answer (score 9):

[Using System Variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/using-system-variables.html):

> To indicate explicitly that a variable is a session variable, precede
> its name by SESSION, @@session., or @@.

[User-Defined Variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/user-variables.html):

> User variables are written as @var_name, where the variable name
> var_name consists of alphanumeric characters, “.”, “_”, and “$”. A
> user variable name can contain other characters if you quote it as a
> string or identifier (for example, @'my-var', @"my-var", or
> @`my-var`).

Answer (score 2):

From the same [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/set-statement.html) & [using system variable docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/using-system-variables.html) -

> To indicate explicitly that a variable is a global variable, precede
>   its name by GLOBAL or @@global.. The SUPER privilege is required to
>   set global variables.
>
> To indicate explicitly that a variable is a session variable, precede
>   its name by SESSION, @@session., or @@. Setting a session variable
>   requires no special privilege, but a client can change only its own
>   session variables, not those of any other client.
>
> LOCAL and @@local. are synonyms for SESSION and @@session..
>
> The @@var_name syntax for system variables is supported for compatibility with some other database 
>   systems.